# Android start preview failed in countdowntimer

Tags: android, camera, android-service, countdowntimer

I created a service in which I try to open the camera in background and take pictures for a period of time. It is running and is taking some pictures, but for example when the countdowntimer reaches 5 sec it crashes. E/AndroidRuntime(10168): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "unused" })
public class PhotoTakingService extends Service {
    static Camera camera = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // takePhoto(this);
        try {
            camera = Camera.open(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (camera != null)
                camera.release();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        showMessage("Service onStartCommand");

        new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.i("seconds remaining: ",
                        String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                takePhoto(getApplicationContext(),
                        String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
                showMessage("photoTaken at "
                        + String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            }

            public void onFinish() {
            //  camera.release();
                //stopService(p);
            }
        }.start();

        return Service.START_STICKY;

    }

    private static void takePhoto(final Context context, final String time) {
        final SurfaceView preview = new SurfaceView(context);
        SurfaceHolder holder = preview.getHolder();
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        holder.addCallback(new Callback() {
            @Override
            // The preview must happen at or after this point or takePicture
            // fails
            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                showMessage("Surface created");

                try {

                    showMessage("Opened camera");

                    try {
                        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }

                    camera.startPreview();
                    showMessage("Started preview");

                    camera.takePicture(null, null, new PictureCallback() {

                        @Override
                        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                            showMessage("Took picture");

                            // decode the data obtained by the camera into a
                            // Bitmap

                            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                            try {
                                outStream = new FileOutputStream(Environment
                                        .getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                        + File.separator
                                        + "/traLaLaDownload/Images/Image"
                                        + time + ".jpg");
                                outStream.write(data);
                                outStream.close();

                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
                            }

                            //camera.release();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    if (camera != null)
                        camera.release();
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            }

            @Override
            public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                    int width, int height) {
            }
        });

        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(1,
                1, // Must be at least 1x1
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY, 0,
                // Don't know if this is a safe default
                PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

        // Don't set the preview visibility to GONE or INVISIBLE
        wm.addView(preview, params);
    }

    private static void showMessage(String message) {
        Log.i("Camera", message);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
```

log

02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198): Process: com.duktech.tralala, PID: 12198
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198): java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at com.duktech.tralala.utils.PhotoTakingService$2.surfaceCreated(PhotoTakingService.java:400)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:572)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:86)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:175)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:847)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1871)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5633)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:743)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5196)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: startPreview failed
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at android.hardware.Camera.startPreview(Native Method)
02-12 12:54:55.726: E/AndroidRuntime(12198):    at com.duktech.tralala.utils.PhotoTakingService$2.surfaceCreated(PhotoTakingService.java:366)

Comment: we need to see the exact logcat output please...

Comment: The surface can be destroyed and recreated (esp. in background), you need to stop the preview in `surfaceDestroyed`